# `fields` is marked as required in `ReduxForm(<MyComp>)`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: redux, redux-form

I'm trying to use `redux-form`

```
// rootRedcer.ts
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

import translation from './translation/reducer'

export default combineReducers({
    form: formReducer,
    translation,
})
```

```
// components/DashboardHome/index.tsx
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import DashboardHome from './Home'

export default connect()(DashboardHome)
```

```
// components/DashboardHome/DashboardHome.tsx
import * as React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

function handleSubmit(value) { console.log(value) }

const DashboardHome = () => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
            <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
)

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'registration'
})(DashboardHome)
```

But I get an error

```
Failed prop type: The prop `fields` is marked as required in 
`ReduxForm(DashboardHome)`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

What is the reason of error? What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded my 'react' and 'react-dom' package from the current version(v16.8.4) to 16.6.3, and the error is gone. There might be a conflict between react-dom and redux-form.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading didn't work for me.
Switched to 
[`formik`](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik)

As I see `redux-form` has broken changes. [Demo example doesn't work](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/4410)